# Append MSE value from random forest iterations varying mtry values into a data frame in R

Tags: r

I am building a random forest. I am trying to append the MSE values from the model into a dataframe while varying the mtry values. I am attaching mock data and a mock RF (not my real analysis, solely looking to use the methodology on my true random forest model).

```
#Load the package
library(randomForest)

#Load in mock data
data("quakes")

#Create a for loop to iterate on mtry
for(i in 1:4) {
  temp.model <- randomForest(mag ~ ., data = quakes, mtry = i)
}

temp.model$mse
```

Is there a way I can append the MSE for the 4 models (which vary the mtry value) in a dataframe? The goal would be to plot the MSE to visualize the trees. I have tried a few different things to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: I need a dataframe that has 500 rows (the ntree default value) and 4 columns (the varying mtry values) of MSE values. I ran your code but received this- 
Error in colnames : 
  The pipe operator requires a function call as RHS (<input>:1:109)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(randomForest))
data("quakes")
mt = 1L:4L
x = as.data.frame(vapply(mt, 
                         \(i) randomForest(mag ~ ., data = quakes, mtry = i)$mse, 
                         numeric(500L))) |> 
  `colnames<-`(paste0("mtry", mt))
plot(x = mt, y = colMeans(x), type = "l", xlab = "", ylab = "MSE", xaxt = "n")
axis(1L, at = mt, labels = paste0("mtry", mt))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect. x gives me the df I needed- thank you for the help.